# Multilanguage web site

Tags: asp.net

How do I make a web site with more languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make something like language files which are to be read if a language is selected, and set the default to English or whatever your default language is.

Answer (score 4):

[ASP.NET Globalization and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx) :

**Globalization** is the process of designing and developing applications that function for multiple cultures.

**Localization** is the process of customizing your application for a given culture and locale.